# Map mac keyboard at symbol to my windows 10 double quote and vice versa with double quote key?

Tags: mac, chrome-remote-desktop

I'm using chrome remote desktop to access my windows 10 machine. I have UK language set on both.

In my `Configure Key mappings` I have..

```
Digit2 => Quote
MetaLeft => ControlLeft
Quote => Digit2
```

This is the best I've managed so far..
But it does mean I can't use my number 2 key whole using 10.

You don't seem to be able to use `shift` and another key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know  Chrome Remote specifically, but in general a UK PC keyboard has @ on shift ' and " on shift 2. If you switch the remote's keyboard to International English, those two will swap back to where they are on Mac, 2/@ and '/".

International English has a slight downside though. It doesn't have dead-keys like on Mac for typing accents, instead if you type for instance ' followed by an e it will give you é. You need to tap Space to prevent this.